# How to shut off window's graphics to save battery life while my program is running?

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a program that i could run on my laptop for long trips to save battery life. What I would like to happen is that is would shut down everything windows does that is not necessary to running programs (IE: shutting ALL the windows graphics.)   , and my program would just be a form with several icons in it to the programs I need the most.  I'm not sure how would go about creating this, or if it would truly help for that matter.

Thanks

Comment: No I mean turn off the OS's graphics. Things like aero or even have it not draw the desktop at all. So that the OS is doing the minimal amount needed to run programs.

Comment: I doubt that shutting off window graphics would save much battery. Windows has built-in power profiles which can be switched on manually or automatically when unplugged. You can also probably get programs to underclock your CPU and possibly GPU which will probably also save significant power.

Comment: BlongBeard is right. That kind of stuff doesn't take up battery life. Especially if your laptop is pretty new and has Intel Turbo Boost built into your CPU. Turbo Boost is a newer technology that automatically adjusts your CPU load based on what's running, thus saving battery life

Answer (score 2):

When you say "Shut off window's graphics", do you mean shut down the monitor? You can do this in the operating system by right clicking on the desktop, clicking on properties, then clicking on Screen Saver and then clicking on the Power button.

If you want to do this programmically, have a look at this article: http://fci-h.blogspot.com/2007/03/turn-off-your-monitor-via-code-c.html

It will show you how to programmically turn off your monitor using C#.

To save your battery life, things that help would be to shut off the screen, turn off WiFi and bluetooth and don't keep programs running that keep your hard drive running and also unplug any USB or PCMCIA devices that you are not running.

Hope this helps!